# How to define a function with one parameter is derivative of another unkown function? and how to take its derivative?

Tags: function-construction

like this
$f\left(\text{y$\_$}(\text{x$\_$}),\text{y$\_$}'(\text{x$\_$})\right)\text{:=}\frac{\sqrt{y'(x)^2+1}}{\sqrt{y(x)}}$

and how to take derivatives with respect to $y$.
this equation comes from the Brachistochrone problem

Comment: This does not look like a useful formulation. What exactly are you trying to do with the brachistochrone? There are other easier approaches to tackling it.

Comment: How to define a function like this?

Comment: If such a function gets defined, what will you be doing with it afterwards?

Comment: Substitute in the Euler-Lagrange equation， to get y(x).